# What are Normal Sets (Fréchet)?

Tags: ho.history-overview, gn.general-topology

In 1913, LEJ Brouwer started a new approach to give a topologist's definition of the notion dimension ("Über den natürlichen Dimensionsbegriff", Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik, 142, 1913, pp. 146--152".) In this paper, Brouwer starts with a "Normalmenge" (Normal Set), referring to Maurice René Fréchet.

- Can anyone explain in modern terms by which properties Normal Sets are characterized?
- Where can Fréchets definition be found?

Comment: Meanwhile, I think what Brouwer meant is called Normal spaces today.

Answer (score 3):

The "normal sets" are separable metric spaces with no isolated points, as introduced by Fréchet in [*Sur quelques points du calcul fonctionnel*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03018603), Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo **22**, 1-74 (1906). See in particular pages 23-24, where the "*classes normales*" are defined as being [1] "*parfaites, séparables et admettant une généralisation du théorème de Cauchy*".

For an extensive discussion of Brouwer's paper in the historical context see D.M. Johnson's 1981 article in the [Archive for History of Exact Sciences](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02116242). Johnson notes that Brouwer is largely following F. Hausdorff's *Grundzüge der Mengenlehre* in his classification of the normal sets.

---

[1] The reference to Cauchy's theorem is the requirement that the limit of every subsequence of a sequence converging to an element $A$ is also $A$.

Comment: So "généralisation du théorème de Cauchy" perhaps is completeness.

Answer (score 1):

The most complete study in English of Fréchet's work that I know of is a series of three long papers (total of 217 pages) by Angus Ellis Taylor that were published in the 1980s:

*A study of Maurice Fréchet: I. His early work on point set theory and the theory of functionals*, **Archive for History of Exact Sciences** 27 #3 (1982), 233-295.

*A study of Maurice Fréchet: II. Mainly about his work on general topology, 1909–1928*, **Archive for History of Exact Sciences** 34 #4 (1985), 279-380.

*A study of Maurice Fréchet: III. Fréchet as analyst, 1909–1930*, **Archive for History of Exact Sciences** 37 #1 (1987), 25-76.

Near the top of p. 256 of the first paper Taylor writes:

> In a number of theorems Fréchet deals with $V$-classes that are complete and separable. He calls them *normal*. This terminology has not survived; in later developments of abstract topology the word normal is given an entirely different meaning.